# Select always selecting the last value

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to search products by brand , so i created this select but it only selects the last option from the list .

```
<select name="brand_id" >
    <option>Brand</option>
    <?php 
        $get_brands = "select * from brands";
        $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

        while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)) {
            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id']; 
            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

           echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";

        }


    ?>

</select>
<?php
    echo "$brand_title<a href='results2.php?brand_id=$brand_id'>Search</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a link for all of the brands?

Comment: If you want to pass the selection to the results2 page, you can't do it like that.  You have to either use a Form or capture the value and send it through ajax.

Comment: That is looping on every brand, filling the `select` element's `option`. Then you are simply echoing out the last looped on item. You need to restructure this entirely if you are trying to search by the selection.

Comment: Delete `<a href='results2.php?brand_id=$brand_id'>Search</a>` put `<form action="results2.php">` around the whole `while` then put a `<input type="submit" value="Search"></form>` after the `while`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.